# Opening and preprocessing text (300 PDFs) in Python

Tags: python, pdf, text-processing

I am supposed to preprocess some PDFs in a folder. I am supposed to remove punctuation, make everything lower case and remove stopwords, and add some extra data from another CSV to it (as metadata). But I cannot even open them. All the googling does not help, since I do not understand the error message (none of the examples from other people helped, since they had different data types).

This is my code so far:

```
import PyPDF2
import re

for k in range(1,312):
    # open the pdf file
    object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader("/Users/n_n/Desktop/Digitalization/reserve" % (k))
```

and this is what happens

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [37], in <cell line: 4>()
      2 import re
      4 for k in range(1,312):
      5     # open the pdf file
----> 6     object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader("/Users/n_n/Desktop/Digitalization/reserve" % (k))

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: You're going to need to make time especially if you're new to Python and you've been set this challenge. btw - the error message is self-explanatory. Also, if you're trying to process 300 files why do you have a range of 311?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to add the string formatting parameter:

```
object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader("/Users/n_n/Desktop/Digitalization/reserve%s" % k)
```

Note the `"%s"` at the end of the file path string. When formatting with the `%` operator, the `"%s"` is replaced by the formatting argument you pass, which in this case it's `str(k)`.

Comment: You don't need to convert the integer `k` to a string with `str(k)`. Python does that automatically when formatting the string with the `%` operator.